# g++: 'vector' file not found

Tags: c++, macos, g++

I'm trying to compile a `cpp` file using `llvm-g++-4.2` on Mac OSX 10.8.
Yes, I know those are old, but I'm trying to develop a plugin for a software that only supports plugins developed in that old environment, sadly.

Anyway, when I try to compile my .cpp file it gives me the error:

> 'vector' file not found

After it tried to include it (`#include <vector>`).
I checked in my local include folder (/usr/include) and the vector header file is really not there.

What should I do?

Comment: I am not sure which version of mac os you have but have you tried installing Xcode's developer tools?

Comment: Yes, i installed it. And the version is 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Comment: have you looked into /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/vector  or - /usr/include/<c++/<version>/vector

Comment: There's a file called 'vector' there but it has no extension.. is that it?

Answer (score -1):

The **CAPlayThrough** example I was looking at compiled just fine, but the project I had created did not.

To tell the compiler to look for the  C++ include file, the top level file AppDelegate.m in my case had to be renamed to AppDelegate.mm. This is telling the compiler to treat the source as a C++ file with all the appropriate includes.